# Angular 2 ngx-Datatable celltemplate

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement cellTemplates in ngx-Datatable (https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) but can’t figure out why it doesn’t work.

First my view

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="skifte?.utsade" [columnMode]="flex" [selectionType]="'single'" [columns]="columns" (select)='edit($event)'></ngx-datatable>
```

I have a template class like this.

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector:'',
template:"
<template #checkbox let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index">
    <md-checkbox checked="value === 'true'"></md-checkbox> 
</template>"
})
export class CellTemplates{

@ViewChild('checkbox') public checkbox: TemplateRef<any>;

constructor(){

 }    
}
```

And try to use it like this. But there are no changes in style of that cell.

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'dv-utsade-table',
templateUrl: 'UtsadeTableComponent.html'

})
export class UtsadeTableComponent extends InsatsComponentBase {

columns : any[];
constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) {
    super();
}
ngAfterViewInit(){
 window.setTimeout(() =>
     this.columns =  [{ name: 'Körning', prop: 'korning'  },
        { name: 'benamning' },
        { name: 'giva' },
        { name: 'areal' },  
        { name: 'Utförd', prop: 'utford', cellTemplate: new CellTemplates().checkbox } //<----Here,
        { name: 'datum' },
        { name: 'Huvudgröda', prop: 'huvudgroda' },
        { name: 'Gödsel', prop: 'godsel.benamning' },
        { name: 'Giva', prop: 'godsel.giva' }
        ]
    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off ngx-datatable has

> checkboxable: boolean
>
> Indicates whether the column should show a checkbox component for
>   selection. Only applicable when the selection mode is checkbox.

so you can tell it that your column should be of checkboxes. 
Second, 
If you really need a custom template with a conponent you need to create a valid component and you can then include it in a template to be used in a cell:

```
<template #chkBxTmpl let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index">
  <checkbox-component [state]="value"></checkbox-component>
</template>
```

and in the component:

```
@ViewChild('chkBxTmpl') chkBxTmpl: TemplateRef:<any>; 
    ....
   this.columns = [
       ...
      {
        cellTemplate: this.chkBxTmpl, 
        prop: 'checked',
        name: 'checked',
        width: 100
      }
    ....
   ];
```

Comment: Problem was that you can't just create a instance of my template class (the view don't render, wich make sense)
Solved by using @ViewChild on the whole templates component.

Comment: can u pl check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303630/how-to-use-edit-and-delete-options-in-angular-ngx-datatables